# How to add foreign_key pointing to same table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, relationship

I've got a table 'users' but one user might be a manager of another user, one user could also be a manager of many other users, so its a one-to-many relationship, and it only involes one table. heres my approach:

1.I've added 'manager_id'(which really stores another uners id) column to users table.

2.I've defined relationship in User model class:

```
  belongs_to :manager, foreign_key: 'manager_id',class_name:'User'
  has_many :minions, class_name:'User'
```

Now, say in rails console if i set one users 'manager_id' to another users id its all fine. but if i try to use methods like 'user.manager' or 'user.minions' it says those methods aren't defined. Were have i gone wrong?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `minions' for #<User:0x00000004c00ec8>

Comment: You should do with an instance of  class, not on a class itself. Try `User.find(1).minions` or `User.find(1).manager`

Comment: I am doing this iwth an instance. i think the part ' for #<User:0x00000004c00ec8>' shows that clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to implement self inheritance that can be done as :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = :child_class
  has_many :minions, :foreign_key => :parent_id, :as => :parent
  belongs_to :parent, :polymorphic => true
end
```

This is just a sketch of what i understood from the above description, it can be enhanced.

Comment: not quite. I think the problem is, that none of the user relationships area loaded. I did EXACT same thing on test dummy classes and it works! 
also, to make this more clear, i've got class Objective it has 'user_id' column and is related to user:

**** belongs_to :user, foreign_key:'user_id', class_name:'User' ****
now in a console if i do objective.user it DOES return correct user. however, even though i have defined relationship in user aswell: **** has_many :objectives **** if i I try to do something like ' user1.objectives' it throws method not defined error again... Why this happens?